# Video tag add crossorigin="anonymous" , file does not load (Chrome browser)

Tags: extjs, html5-canvas, cross-domain, html5-video

view page)

```
<video crossorigin="anonymous"  controls preload="none" style="width: 100%;height: 150;"><source src="' + src + '" type="video/mp4"></video>');
```

file not load(video play failed)

Extjs store

```
var playerStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Player',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8; Cache-Control: no-cache;',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization'
        },
        noCache: false,
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

What should I do?